# Unity Firebase Analytics 6.15.2 crash

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, crash, analytics

I have implemented Firebase Analytics 6.15.2 into my project, then I have builded the Xcode project and have run it on the device, everything went perfect, but when I try to open the app afterwards, without it running from Xcode - it crashes after 20 seconds of launch screen.

So I have no logs and anything, I somehow figured out it's an issue with Firebase and downgraded the pods in the Xcode project to Firebase 5.3.0, it worked.

I have other projects where the same issue is occurring.

So my question is, how do I fix it? Because there is no way it's happening to everyone, I might be doing something wrog here and I just don't see it.

I use Unity 2020.1.2f1
Firebase Core + Analytics 6.15.2 via Package Manager (also tried installing it manually, still the same)
Other plugins I am using are Facebook and ironSource

ps. The funny thing that it crashes on all devices, but it passes Apple review because they test it in some kind of debug mode, but when it's in release mode - it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall Firebase Analytics 6.15.2? Also, you can try to restart your device and try to make it work again.

Comment: The thing is that I have send the game to Appstore and it was approved and it crashed on all devices an all users o_O I quickly send an update with Firebase 5.3.0 which fixed the crash

Comment: I guess the problem might lie with this latest version in particular, since the same issue occurs with other projects. Have you contacted Firebase Google Group about it?

Comment: I am also curious if the problem lie with the integration of Firebase Analytics 6.15.2 with Unity. Try to make it work with another version of unity like 2019.

Comment: It's the same with older versions of Unity, I guess I will contact Google to see if they have an answer to that

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the debug symbols to your app debug archive file:

> Select your Target -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug
> Information Format

Then Select `DWARF with dSYM file` for the **debug mode**.